# Laravel Policy for a large array of permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

I am looking to use Laravel's policy to authorize a large array of user permissions with Blade.

- My authorizations are under a `ActionPermission` model holding all app permissions.
- `User` has his permission names accessed via a pivot

using:

```
public function permissions(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\ActionPermission', 'users__action_permission');
}
```

So essentially I am receiving a collection of permissions for user and calling `$user->permissions()->pluck('module_name')->toArray();` I will get the names of permissions as array.

Is there a way to bring an array of policies via blade in one line? So in my layout I will insert a one line blade directive?

In Laravel's docs, they use the name of the function as the blade directive, like this in the policy:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```

And in the blade:

```
@can('update', $post)
    <!-- The Current User Can Update The Post -->
@elsecan('create', App\Post::class)
    <!-- The Current User Can Create New Post -->
@endcan
```

The above isn't relevant when you have a large number of permissions.
What would be the best practice to execute a large array of permissions?

BTW any method (not only provider bootstrap) would be welcome.

Comment: Why do this yourself, just use package https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the model to create from the blade can be dangerous, as you're skipping some validation and requiring Eloquent to handle everything well (it won't).

Aside from that, I hope this can explain what you seek:

```
$user = User::find($idOfUser) // retrieves an active record of User
$user->permissions // gets the record of permissions that is related to the user, believing the relationship is estabished

User::find($idOfUser)->permissions->update($data) // updates the record in permissions that is related to that user
```